# How to make the header skip the first page

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I just want the header that I'm printing to skip the first page of my PDF document, right now it is printing on all my pages. What am I Missing, or need to change in my code.

I think the way to get the code to do what I want would be either in the `OnEndPage()` or the `OnCloseDocument()`

```
public override void OnEndPage(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document document)
{
    var titleFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);

    base.OnEndPage(writer, document);

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(9);
    table.SetWidths(new float[] { 6, 8, 10, 15, 8, 6, 10, 10, 8 });
    table.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width - 78;
    table.WidthPercentage = 93;

    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Ticket #", titleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK; cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY; cell.Padding = 5; table.AddCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Technician", titleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK; cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY; cell.Padding = 5; table.AddCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Address", titleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK; cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY; cell.Padding = 5; table.AddCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Descripton", titleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK; cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY; cell.Padding = 5; table.AddCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Severity", titleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK; cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY; cell.Padding = 5; table.AddCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Status", titleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK; cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY; cell.Padding = 5; table.AddCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Date Logged", titleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK; cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY; cell.Padding = 5; table.AddCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Date Resolved", titleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK; cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY; cell.Padding = 2; table.AddCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" ", titleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK; cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY; cell.Padding = 2; table.AddCell(cell);

    table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 39, document.PageSize.Height - 15, writer.DirectContent);
}

public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document document)
{
    base.OnCloseDocument(writer, document);

    headerTemplate.BeginText();
    headerTemplate.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
    headerTemplate.SetTextMatrix(0, 0);
    headerTemplate.ShowText((writer.PageNumber - 1).ToString());
    headerTemplate.EndText();
}
```

Comment: In `OnEndPage` you can start by querying the current page from the `writer` or the `document`. If the current page is the first one, skip adding the header.

Comment: ah yes. Thank you I was thinking along those lines and tried it before but I must have done it wrong. 

I created an ```int pageNumber = 1;``` just added a simple if statement

```if (pageNumber != writer.PageNumber)
{
//headercode
}```